# CPU face flipping vs GPU face flipping?

Tags: performance, directx, gpu, cpu, hlsl

Assuming the following shader code, would it be more efficient to generate the other side of a triangle on the CPU: letting the GPU translate double the amount of vertices by the instance/worldmatrix, or to generate it on the GPU: copying the vertices in a different order and flipping the normal?

Interesting pieces of shader code:

```
struct VS_IN
{
    float4 pos : POSITION;
    float3 norm : NORMAL;
    matrix instance : INSTANCEMATRIX;
    float4 color : INSTANCECOLOR;
};

struct PS_IN
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float3 norm : NORMAL;
    float4 color: COLOR;
};

cbuffer viewProj : register (b0)
{
    matrix viewProj;
} 

PS_IN VS(VS_IN input)
{
    PS_IN output = (PS_IN)0;

    output.pos = mul(mul(input.pos, input.instance), viewProj);
    output.norm = normalize(mul(input.norm, (float3x3)input.instance));
    output.color = input.color;

    return output;
};

[maxvertexcount(6)]
void FlipFaceGS(triangle PS_IN input[3], inout TriangleStream<PS_IN> OutputStream)
{
    OutputStream.Append(input[0]);
    OutputStream.Append(input[1]);
    OutputStream.Append(input[2]);
    OutputStream.RestartStrip();

    input[0].norm = -input[0].norm;
    input[1].norm = -input[1].norm;
    input[2].norm = -input[2].norm;

    OutputStream.Append(input[0]);
    OutputStream.Append(input[2]);
    OutputStream.Append(input[1]);
    OutputStream.RestartStrip();
}

technique10 Render
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_4_0, VS()));
        SetGeometryShader(CompileShader(gs_4_0, FlipFaceGS()));
        SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_4_0, PS()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the keyword is culling, because your approach seems to be targeting at bypassing it.

Instead of doubling your geometry, where culling would remove the invisible half afterwards, you should simply turn culling off (set `D3D11_CULL_NONE` [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ff476108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and use the pixelshader input semantic `SV_IsFrontFace` ([doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to flip the normal in your pixelshader if needed.

Comment: This is probably going to solve all my issues, thanks!